# error while trying to run the provider hosted app to SharePoint online

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Recently I was trying to create a provider hosted app to share point online.
I have configured Azure web apps and created the app and published it to share point online. I can now see the app in the SharePoint online appcataloge. but when I tried to run the application it is throwing the below error.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: msoidcliL.dll at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlNativeMethodsSelector..ctor(String dllPath) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.get_IdcrlNativeMethods() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.EnsureInited() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.LogonIdentity(String username, SecureString password) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.Logon(String username, SecureString password) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(String username, SecureString password) at SharePointApp5Web.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Code

```
 var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

        try
        {
            string str;
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/HR/Acknowledgements"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("myname@domain.com", ConvertToSecureString("password"));

                Web myweb = ctx.Web;
                List myList = myweb.Lists.GetByTitle("Timesheet Administration Policy");
                ListItemCreationInformation ItemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml =
                    @"<Query>
                   <Where>
                      <Neq>
                         <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                         <Value Type='Counter'>946</Value>
                      </Neq>
                   </Where>
                </Query>";


                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItems = myList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                ctx.Load(listItems);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();


                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in listItems.ToList())
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            Response.Write(listItem["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString().Trim());

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the CSOM dll. Please install the latest CSOM online version and then deploy/publish your code.

Go to your project references in Visual studio, right to open `Manage Nuget packages` as below:

[image]

Search for CSOM and install the `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM`

[image]

Or, alternately, you can download it from the Microsoft download link mentioned below and add the references manually:

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Also, ensure that .NET framework is targeted to `v4.5` and the platform target is set to `Any CPU`. Also, ensure that the v16 assemblies are referenced.

Also, add the following code below the `ctx.Credentials` line:

```
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
```

Comment: can you also add this line `ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;` below the `ctx.Credentials` line and check ? Also, ensure that your project is targetted to .Net framework 4.5 and platform target is set to `Any CPU`. Ensure that its v16 assemblies

Comment: Worked like a charm !!! :). Can you update the answer ? so that i can mark it as answer.